# Remove everything outside of the brackets Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is what I am trying to remove strings from:

```
var myl = 'okok{"msg":"uc_okok"}'
```

and the results should be:

```
{"msg":"uc_okok"}
```

I have tried using regex

```
var news = myl.toString().replace(/ \{(.*""?)\}/g);
```

but it's not working? Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about using the following;

```
myl.toString().replace(/.*?({.*}).*/, "$1")
```

It should work with multiple layers of brackets as well;

```js
str = 'okok{"msg":"uc_okok"}';
console.log(str.replace(/.*?({.*}).*/, "$1"));

str = 'adgadga{"okok":{"msg":"uc_okok"}}adfagad';
console.log(str.replace(/.*?({.*}).*/, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 9):

I presume `okok..` is a string

```js
var d = 'okok{"msg":"uc_okok"}'

console.log(d.slice(d.indexOf('{'), d.lastIndexOf('}') + 1))
```

Comment: It should be `d.lastIndexOf('}')` otherwise fails with `adgadga{"okok":{"msg":"uc_okok"}}adfagad`

Comment: GIven the input with only string, I did only "indexOf", but to cater objects, you are correct. Done Editing!!

Answer (score 5):

```js
s = 'okok{"msg":"uc_okok"}';
s = '{' + s.split('{')[1].split('}')[0] + '}';

console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 5):

Also you can simply extract the string between brackets as below;

```
var myl = "okok{\"msg\":\"uc_okok\"}okok";
var mylExtractedStr = myl.match('\{.*\}')[0];

console.log(mylExtractedStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use this code - it splits the item into an array, and removes the first element:

```
var news = myl.toString().split("{").shift().unshift("{").join("");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instead *capture* it:

```js
var myString = 'okok {"msg":"uc_okok"} bla bla bla';
var myRegexp = /({[^{}]*})/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

This could be put in a loop (`while...`) but won't work for nested brackets:

```js
var myString = 'okok {"msg":"uc_okok"} bla bla bla {"msg":"uc_okok212121"} lorem ipsum';
var myRegexp = /({[^{}]*})/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);

while(match !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```